# $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}} = 0$, where is my mistake?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, fake-proofs

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$, but when I evaluate it as follows I get $0$ as the result:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{n \left (\sin \frac{1}{n} \right) ^2}{\sin \frac{1}{n}} \right) \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \left( \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) ^2 \frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}} \right) \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) ^2 \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}} \\
& \underset{\text{L'Hôpital}}{=} \left( \sin \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \right) \right) ^2 \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\cos \frac{1}{n}} \\
& = \left( \sin 0 \right) ^2 \frac{1}{\cos \left( \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \right) } \\
& = 0^2 \frac{1}{\cos 0} \\
& = 0 \cdot \frac{1}{1} \\
& = 0 \cdot 1 \\
& = 0
\end{align}

Where is my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  The limit of the products equals the product of the limits **when the limits are defined**

Comment: *Heuristically* (i.e., in this case, very loosely), you broke the expression up into $\frac{1}{\infty^2} \times \frac{\infty}{1/\infty}$. To use L'Hôpital's Rule, you want to break it up so that the fractions have "equal degrees" of infinity. Otherwise, as @J.W.Tanner points out, neither part is defined and you end up with a nonsensical result (even if it happens by pure luck to be right).

Comment: Incidentally, I'm going to edit your post so that we see each step as a separate line. Feel free to revert if you think it's misleading to do so, but as it stands, one of your steps is broken across the two lines (at least when it renders for me).

Answer (score 5):

> Where is my mistake?

You cannot say $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \left( \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) ^2 \frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}} \right)
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) ^2 \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}},$$ because the limit of the products equals the product of the limits **when the limits are defined**,

and $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use L'Hopital's rule to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}},$$
as it is not of the form $\frac{\to 0}{\to 0}$ or $\frac{\to \infty}{\to \infty}.$ In fact, the fraction $\frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}$ approaches $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Since this limit does not exist (i.e., it is not finite) - the splitting of the limit of the product of two functions into a product of limits is not justified.

Answer (score 3):

As noticed we can't do this step

$$\ldots= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \left( \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) ^2 \frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}} \right)
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) ^2 \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}=\ldots$$

because you have factorized in an indeterminate form $0 \cdot \infty$ which is not allowed, as for example in the case

$$1=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac n n \neq \lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1 n $$